# Why are null values inserted into the table?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to insert name and age into the HTML table using a prompt. But it inserts null values in the result, Can you implement a solution for this? Thank you in advance!

```js
var i = 0;
var n = new Array();
var a = new Array();
var name = " ",
  age = " ";

while (!(name == null || age == null)) {
  name = prompt("Enter name: ");
  age = prompt("Enter age: ");
  n[i] = name;
  a[i] = age;
  i++;
}

document.writeln("<table border='1' width='25%'>");
document.writeln("<caption>Arrays</caption>");
document.writeln("<th>Name</th><th>Age</th>");

for (var k in n) {
  if (!(k == null))
    document.writeln("<tr><td>" + n[k] + "</td><td>" + a[k] + "</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>
<p>JavaScript array elements are accesses using numeric indexes (starting from 0).</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Because you are literally adding them to your array at `n[i] = name;` and `a[i] = age;` without checking.

Comment: `document.write` and `document.writeln` are [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/4642212) for DOM manipulations, as they are obsolete, slow and not suitable for any evolving application. Write `if (k != null)` instead of `if (!(k == null))`. Use `[]` instead of `new Array()` and [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) instead of index assignment.

Comment: Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. [Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code.

Comment: Why you are not using push()  ?

Comment: I corrected my mistakes because of your help, Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompt function returns `null` on Cancel/Esc.

This is explained in the [MDN documentation of prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt). To avoid printing `null` in your html table, you need to print it only if it exists.

Here is your code with the right condition:

```js
var i = 0;
var n = new Array();
var a = new Array();
var name = " ",
  age = " ";

while (!(name == null || age == null)) {
  name = prompt("Enter name: ");
  age = prompt("Enter age: ");
  n[i] = name;
  a[i] = age;
  i++;
}

document.writeln("<table border='1' width='25%'>");
document.writeln("<caption>Arrays</caption>");
document.writeln("<th>Name</th><th>Age</th>");

for (var k in n) {
  if(n[k] !== null && a[k] !== null)
    document.writeln("<tr><td>" + n[k] + "</td><td>" + a[k] + "</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>
<p>JavaScript array elements are accesses using numeric indexes (starting from 0).</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are checking the null values before the prompt. Use the condition after name or age is provided.

```
while(true){
   name=prompt("Enter name: ");
   age=prompt("Enter age: ");
   if(name==null || age==null) break;
   n[i]=name;
   a[i]=age;
   i++;
}
```